# Do I need permission "Public page content" to read page posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

At the moment I use the facebook api to read out the posts of public pages via //posts. I use this data to show on a display in the store the latest facebook post that the store placed on their page.

we have a lot stores that use this, but of most pages I don't have an access token so I use the app access token to read it. However I did receive a warning that I need to request the "Public page content" permission. So I requested it but denied with message "We determined that your app's use case for this permission is invalid, or it's not needed to support its core functionality."

I think I needs this permission, I also think this is an allowed use case.

I did explain why I needed the permission, and uploaded a screencast of how the screen looks like.

Am I missing something? or do I not need the permission to read public posts of a page? (Wish the explanation was better why the permission was denied)

Comment: Yes, you need to get that feature (not a permission) reviewed, if you want to be able to access public page content without a page or admin user access token. If they said you don’t need it, then you probably didn’t manage to describe the use case to them properly. Or perhaps they are simply of the opinion that you _should_ be using proper page access tokens here, and that mere unwillingness(?) to implement that is not a proper reason to get access to the feature that would allow access to the public data of _all_ pages in the first place …?

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, then I will try it again with better explanation I think.

it is not really unwillingness, but I think it is unnecessary to request access to every facebook page of a store if you only want to read public data. When Customers want to use our system to post to facebook they can link their page to their profile.